# Is a reflexive relation on the set of real numbers infinite?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

In the mathematics textbook which I am studying, it is written that a relation $\mathit{R}$ on a set $\mathit{A}$ is **not** **reflexive** if there exists an element $a \in A$ such that $(a, a) \notin R$. So, for the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, is a reflexive relation $\mathit {R}$  defined on it infinite? If it is finite, there must be at least one element $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(a, a) \notin \mathit{R}$, which would again, make it incorrect, am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, an arbitrary relation $R$ on set $Y$ can be any subset of $Y\times Y$ (cross product). So you should be able to have a finite relation $R$ that is irreflexive.

Comment: The title of your question does not match the body of your question. In your title, you ask about reflexive relations, while in your body, you ask about transitive and symmetric relations.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a transitive and symmetric relation of any cardinality $\leq \mathfrak{c}$. For consider any subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Then the relationship $=_S = \{(s, s) \mid s \in S\}$ is transitive, symmetric, and of cardinality $|S|$.